# VBA code on Hidden Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am building a small piece of VBA code to update the pivot table automatically so that my chart gets updated. After recording the code, I created stored it in the vb script of the sheet.

Here is my code:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh
```

I do not want to show the sheet containing the pivot table. So I hide the sheet, and then the code fails to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `ActiveSheet` to `Worksheets("WorksheetName")`

So you'd have

```
Worksheets("WorksheetName").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh
```

Using ActiveSheet means it performs it on the sheet that is currently selected, last I checked you can't have a hidden sheet selected ;)

Comment: That should be `Worksheets("WorksheetName")`.